# Custom List edit & view options go to root calendar

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I have used sharepoint designer to create some custom forms for viewing & editing list items, however now when I select either of those options the link takes me to the calendar of the root site.

For example it just goes to "http://sharepointserver/ID=1"

Instead of going to "http://sharepointserver/division/department/site/?ID=1"

any suggestions on

Answer (score 1):

Check the below link...!!

http://kishansharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/05/custom-list-forms-and-redirecting-after.html

it might solve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: Kishan, Liked your Blogspot specially your life motto & fish animation , plus 1 for that

Comment: Thanks very much @TimeToThine...!! I love to hear any suggesstion..!!